# scope of nested class with structs

Tags: c++, class, scope

Can some one please explain the scope of `int A` and `int B` in the `void func()` and in `void func1()`?

```
class C {
  struct S {
    int A;
  };

  int B

public :
  void func(){
  }
  void func1(){
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand what you're asking for, but if I do, I'll try to answer.

Functions `func()` and `func1()` are member functions of `C`, so they have identical access to the exact same names here. Variable `B`, being a member variable of `C`, can be referred directly withing `func()` and `func1()` without qualifying it with any namespace.

Variable `A` on the other hand, being a public, non-static member variable of `S`, requires first instantiating an object of type `S` before being accessed, like this:

```
void func()
{
    S s;
    B = 0; // Directly accessible, member variable of `C`
    s.A = B; // A is a non-static member variable of `S`, requires an object
    A == 3; // ERROR! A is not a member variable of C
}
```